# What is the difference between Liferay 5.2 and Sun Glassfish Web Space Server 10

Tags: glassfish, liferay, portal, glassfish-webspace

I'm finding Liferay 5.2 to be fairly buggy (IMO) and more specifically there are a number of security-related bugs that I find very troubling.  Is Sun's version of this product (Glassfish Web Space Server) any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a small amount of time setting up Sun's Webspace server, and immediately noticed several of the same flaws that bothered me about Liferay.  I'm not going to proceed any farther.

Edit: Liferay has an open JIRA site at: http://issues.liferay.com

I won't bother going into details about every bug I looked for, only to say that they existed in both Liferay and Webspace.  I didn't want to spend much time on this.  The Liferay + Sun collaboration thing is pretty new, so I'm not surprised that the two products are so similar.

Answer (score 2):

Webspace Server is based on Liferay 5.2 so chances are if a bug is in LR 5.2 it is in Webspace.  If we find bugs in Webspace, and they are in fact Liferay bugs, they will be fixed in Liferay (not just in Webspace).  That is part of our community commitment to Liferay.

Edit: Sun then produces a commercially-supported product with additional features, docs, services, support, integrations with Sun and non-Sun products.